# cannot use private part

Tags: c++, time-complexity, private-members

I had an exam and they asked about queues. I am wonder how a reverse method can be written without using any private part of the header file given. So the method must be written by using only public part of the file. Also you cannot create a new Queue, or delete the queue existing already. You cannot use inheritance, interface etc.  Also the method is required to work in O(N) time complexity. It is too much required and I could not find a solution for it.

Header file is :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Queue
{

    public:
        Queue();         // Class constructor
        ~Queue();        // Class destuctor
        void ClearQueue();       // Remove all items from the queue
        bool Enqueue(int newItem);   // Enter an item in the queue
        int Dequeue();          // Remove an item from the queue
        bool isEmpty();          // Return true if queue is empty


     private:
        struct Node(){
           Node *next;
           int item;

        };
        Node *front;
        Node *back;
};

//and the prototype of the method wanted :
bool reverse(){


}
```

Comment: So the **non-member-function** `reverse()` in this code is changing... what queue exactly? Or is `reverse()` supposed to be a member function of `Queue`? And the `bool` result represents... what?

Comment: reverse is a global function. the reverse method changes the queue existing and then returns true.

Comment: *the queue existing*... None of the code posted shows *any* existing queue at all. Either there is a global queue object or `reverse` should require a reference parameter of the queue object being changed. Either way, it is code you haven't posted for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a recursive function. Add the following function to your class:

```
bool reverse() {
    if (this->isEmpty())
        return true;
    int value = this->Dequeue();
    this->reverse();
    this->Enqueue(value);
    return true;
}
```

If you don't want the function to be a method of the class Queue and you have a global Queue-object `queue`, you could also write a global function like this:

```
bool reverse() {
    if (queue.isEmpty())
        return true;
    int value = queue.Dequeue();
    queue.reverse();
    queue.Enqueue(value);
    return true;
}
```

If you don't have a global Queue-object, you will have to pass the queue as parameter, see:

```
bool reverse(Queue& queue) {
    if (queue.isEmpty())
        return true;
    int value = queue.Dequeue();
    queue.reverse(queue);
    queue.Enqueue(value);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: sorry for my previous comment, I mixed up a queue and a fifo.

Comment: @Wimmel No Problem, but a queue is a fifo.

Comment: ... use `true` instead of `1`... but it really doesn't matter since you're not using the return value.

Comment: sorry. I wrote what I remembered but it is also a global function, so reverse function changes externally the queue existing and returns true.

Comment: I hope I did not forget anything extra. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @jsantander Thanks! Long time since I wrote c++ code :)

Comment: Actually it is a good job but I realized you change the function prototype of the reverse method. In another way, how we can solve this without changing the reverse method?

Comment: @user3696164 Then the queue object has to be global (like I mentioned in the second code example).

Comment: there is no object given. that is, the given in the question is that. I dont understand the object concept there because if we call reverse method in main function, how we differ a queue object is created in the reverse method from the object created for reverse method in main. They are not same?

Comment: I guess I understand it. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @user3696164 Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Is there just one Queue-object? Or do you just want to have a reversed copy of the queue? Creating an empty Queue-object in the reverse()-Function doesn't make sense if the queue is empty.

Comment: I wondered how 2. version can be done without any queue object given. I tried to create a new queue object in the reverse method. But it does not make sense. I get it. mostly probably your solution is correct. thanks a lot again  :)